# Redirecting to sub-directory not fully displaying URL (.htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, directory

I am using wordpress and am trying to direct a page on my site to another sub directory but it is deleting a directory when loaded.

Example:

**URL to redirect:** `example.com/blog/directory/`

**Target URL:** `example.com/blog/new-directory/more-directory/`

**Final URL:** `example.com/new-directory/more-directory/`

It removes the "blog" directory which then gives me a 404. It would be great for some help on this please

**Update with .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/files/(.*) /files/$1
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/directory/(.*) /blog/new-directory/more-directory/$1

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you using a wordpress redirect?

Comment: Can you show your current .htaccess?

Comment: I'm using the wordpress .htaccess file if that's what you mean?

Comment: Right but where is this redirect rule that is not working?

Comment: I added my htaccess file

Comment: Posted an answer. Is this .htaccess in `/blog/` or a level above?

Comment: The .htaccess is in the `/blog/` but there is also one in the level above

Answer (score 0):

if you can access the page html file of example.com/blog/directory/ just insert the code below in the file

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=example.com/blog/new-directory/more-directory/">
```

Comment: I am unable to do that as it is WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `mod_alias` rule with `mod_rewrite` and have 301 before WP rules.

This should be in your `/blog/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /files/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ new-directory/more-directory/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This belongs to `/blog/.htaccess`. What URL did you enter in browser and what did it become?

Comment: I put it in that directory, and still the same url `example.com/blog/directory/` to redirect to `example.com/blog/new-directory/more-directory/`

Comment: Yes `example.com/blog/directory/` will redirect to `example.com/blog/new-directory/more-directory/` what's wrong?

Comment: The resulting url is `example.com/new-directory/more-directory/` - it takes away the `/blog/`

Comment: Is there `/blog/directory/.htaccess` as well? Also try it out in a new browser.

Comment: There isn't an htaccess file in the directory. Same result in different browser

Comment: Open Firebug's Net tab and then report how many and what redirects do you see when you visit `example.com/blog/directory/`

Comment: /blog
GET 301
Moved Permanently
text/html Other (from cache) 5 ms
5 ms
more-directory/
/new-directory
GET 404
Not Found
text/html http://www.example.com/blog/directory/
Redirect
1.1 KB
898 B
175 ms
174 ms
style.css
/assets/css
GET 200
OK
text/css www.example.com/:24
Parser
(from cache) Pending 
3343a11a5e.jpg
puu.sh/9LaPo
GET 200
OK
image/jpeg www.example.com/:29
Parser
(from cache) Pending

Comment: Looks like you've some conflicting WP plugin. If you have curl command line then better to test it from that.